# Track & Assign Unique IDs to Objects in Video c#

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv, yolo

I am new to Computer Vision and i am using EmguCV library. My goal is to track and assign unique IDs to all objects in a video and i'm almost lost!!.

**Approach 1:**
for each frame in the video:

- Background subtraction using (`BackgroundSubtractorMOG`)
- Get Blobs using (`CvBlobDetector`)
- Track detected Blobs using (`CvTracks`)

The issues in this approach are:

- The same object (ex: person) may be detected as more than one Blob and each one is assigned a different ID.
- If the person/object left the scene or gets occluded by another object in one frame, it is assigned a new ID (lose tracking).

**Approach 2:**
for each frame in the video:

- Detect objects in the frame using [YOLO](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.Yolo)
- Use modern trackers in EmguCV (TLD, KCF) [Trackers](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

The issues in this approach are:

- How to map detected objects in YOLO to trackers in EmguCV?
- If the person/object left the scene or gets occluded by another object in one frame, i lose tracking.
- How to identify the same object in different frames (using color/appearance/features not the location)? what is the best method?

Any help/ideas for these approaches will be very appreciated or new approaches for tracking and ID tagging.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is very broad and open-ended. You should focus on one problem and ask questions about that, right now there are so many broad questions here that any attempt at an answer will just spark a discussion, and not produce an answer. Basically, what you're after is a research group and workshop that can have a discussion at project around this, and that's not really all that suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In short, I think your best option is simply to start researching and testing this, I seriously doubt there's a single "here's how to do it" type of method for this.